# Swift Combine: Unexpected backpressure behaviour with zip operator

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, combine

I've got a question about the `zip` operator in Combine in combination with backpressure.

Take the following code snippet:

```
let sequencePublisher = Publishers.Sequence<Range<Int>, Never>(sequence: 0..<Int.max)
let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

let handle = subject
    .zip(sequencePublisher.print())
    .print()
    .sink { letters, digits in
        print(letters, digits)
    }

subject.send("a")
```

When executing this in the playground, the following is the output:

```
receive subscription: (0..<9223372036854775807)
receive subscription: (Zip)
request unlimited
request unlimited
receive value: (0)
receive value: (1)
receive value: (2)
receive value: (3)
receive value: (4)
receive value: (5)
receive value: (6)
receive value: (7)
...
```

When executing it on an iOS device, the code crashes after a few seconds because of memory issues.

The underlying reason can be seen in the fourth line above where `zip` requests an unlimited amount of values from the `sequencePublisher`. Since the `sequencePublisher` provides the whole range of `Int` values, this causes memory overflows.

What I think to know:

- `zip` waits for one value of each publisher before combining them and pushing them on
- backpressure is used to control the demand from a subscriber to a publisher

My expectation would be that `zip` only requests one value from each publisher, waits for them to arrive and only requests the next values when it received one from each.

In this particular case I tried to build a behaviour where a sequence number is assigned to every value that is produced by the  `subject`. However, I could imagine that this is always a problem when `zip` combines values from publishers that publish with very different frequencies.

Utilising backpressure in the `zip` operator seems to be perfect tool to solve that issue. Do you know why this isn't the case? Is this a bug or intentional? If intentional, why?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Sequence publisher is just unrealistic. It doesn't seem to respond to back pressure; it just spews out the whole sequence at once, which makes no sense in a world where publication is supposed to be asynchronous. If you change `Int.max` to 3 there's no problem. :) I don't know whether it's a bug or just a flaw in the whole notion of a Sequence publisher.

However, there's really no issue for your actual use case, because there is a much better way to assign a successive number to each emission from the Subject, namely `scan`.

Here's a more realistic approach:

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
        subject.scan(("",0)) {t,s in (s,t.1+1)}
            .sink { print($0.0, $0.1)
            }.store(in:&storage)
        delay(1) {
            subject.send("a") // a 1
            delay(1) {
                subject.send("b") // b 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That assumes that you have some other reason for needing each successive enumeration to pass down thru the pipeline. But if your *only* goal is to enumerate each signal as it arrives into the `sink` itself, you can just have the `sink` itself maintain a counter (which it can easily do, because it is a closure):

```
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var counter = 1
        subject
            .sink {print($0, counter); counter += 1}
            .store(in:&storage)
        delay(1) {
            self.subject.send("a") // a 1
            self.subject.send("b") // b 2
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for this great response. I'm quite new to functional programming so its very useful to learn about such kind of recipes.

Comment: Actually my use of `.scan` may be overkill here; if you just need a counter in the `.sink`, you can just configure the `.sink` itself to count. I've added that idea to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Combine's zip operator:

1. forwards the requested backpressure demand from its downstream subscriber to the upstream which is unlimited for the sink
2. buffers the entire sequence from the first upstream

Apart from the scan-based solution, you can avoid the problem by either controlling the downstream's backpressure demand or using a custom zip operator.

I've managed to develop a custom zip operator which works differently from the original one in two ways:

1. Whatever backpressure demand it receives from its downstream, it always sends a demand for only one value to its upstreams, then waits for the response from each of them, and then emits the result downstream, closing the round. It repeats so until the demand gets exhausted.
2. It avoids buffering the whole upstream sequence by using the described "round"-based approach.

The code is a bit extensive to be included here, but feel free to check it out in this repo https://github.com/SergeBouts/XCombine